# Embedded PDF Viewer in a WinForms Control

Tags: .net, winforms, pdf

I'm trying to embed a pdf viewer in a WinForms Control in such a way that I can display the pdf to the user within the context of my application.  I also need to prevent the user from copying text, printing, or saving a copy (sensitive data).

Thus far I've tried using a WebBrowser to host the Acrobat Reader activex control.  This gets me close but leaves me with 2 problems.
1.  Any pdfs I open seem to stay open from a file handle standpoint until the application shuts down.  I've tried calling Dispose() and Navigate() to no avail.
2.  I need to disable the toolbar in Reader.  I can't set the viewer preferences in the original pdf files but I'm considering using iText to rewrite the files with the preferences set (if I can do that).

I'd also be happy with a well recommended 3rd party library that does this.

Answer (score 1):

Re: 1. It kind of sucks but you could make a copy of the PDF to the temp folder

```
Path.GetTempPath()
```

and open that each time the user needed to see that PDF, so you let Reader lock that file all it wants.

Re: 2. Did you try appending

```
toolbar=0
```

to the URL? Ref (and example!) at:

see http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf#toolbar=0

Answer (score -1):

You can use iText to rewrite the files.  I have PDFs created by an external application that I need to email to clients.  I use iText to encrypt them and also change the permissions:

Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
....

```
Dim reader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(fileName)
PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, New FileStream(mailFileName, FileMode.CreateNew), PdfWriter.STRENGTH128BITS, _
    "password", "password", PdfWriter.AllowCopy Or PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING)
```

Answer (score -2):

I'd recommend the [WinForms PDF Viewer](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/pdf-viewer/) UI control by DevExpress (a commercial 3rd party UI library). With its comprehensive API, you can prevent the end-user from copying text, printing, saving a copy, etc.